# Selenium clicks next button instead of back button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to scrape this webpage for prices, and I need the prices to be in US dollars, so it is currency I understand. However, when I initially load the URL, it gives the prices in multiple seemingly random currencies. I found that I could change this by clicking the next button, and then the back button, but when I tried to automate this, it did not work. Instead, running this code clicks the next button twice, rather than clicking it once, waiting for five seconds, and then clicking the back button. Here is the code that I am currently using that can replicate this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara')

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

import time
time.sleep(5)

action = ActionChains(driver)

next_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_next')))
action.move_to_element(next_button).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
back_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_prev')))
action.move_to_element(back_button).click().perform()
```

Thanks, your time and help is greatly appreciated. Please direct me to a relevant question if this one has already been answered somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ActionChains` class, it's works by `.click()` method.

Try following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_next')))
next_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
back_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_prev')))
back_button.click()
```

But note, `time.sleep(5)` is bad way, you can use other way, ex : wait until the second page element appear.

Or instead of `time.sleep(...)` in this case, you can use this code:

```
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pagebtn.disabled')))
```

The above is the `disable previous button` since you landing in the first pagination, and will gone when you arrieve on second pagination. Use **`.invisibility_of_element_located`**, it will more efficient.